# PHP two dimensional array array search

Tags: php

Please help me with the code to search for a particular value in a two-dimensional array and print the values returned in PHP. Thanks in advance.
in the below array i want to search for value  15 and print 12

code:

```
$speed = array 
(
 array(5,4),
 array(10,8),
 array(15,12),
 array(20,16),
 array(25,20),
 array(30,24),
 array(35,28),
 array(40,32),
 array(45,36),
 array(51,40),
 array(56,44)
);

foreach ($speed as $key => $val)
 {

}
```

Comment: Sure. Now show us your codes. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($speed as $key => $val)
{
    if($val[0] === 15)
    {
        echo $val[1];
    }           
}
```

$val is an array so first index is your search and second is your value.

Answer (score 0):

When you browse the array, a row is an array in your input. So if you want to check for 15 and to print 12, you have to do :

```
// For each row of my array $speed, I have an array that I will call $arr
foreach($speed as $arr){
    if(15 == $arr[0]) {
        echo $arr[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sahana It's my pleasure ^.^, set the most efficient answer as the accepted one when you are up to ! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use in_array

loop through the array and search for the value in the array using in array

```
foreach ($speed as $key => $val)
 {

 echo (in_array(15, $val)) ? $val[1] :NULL;


}
```